# How to add platform specific files to NuGet package?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a custom control for Xamarin Forms and now I'm creating a NuGet package for the same. The issue I'm facing is, I'm having a class which is UWP specific which is being used by my custom control. How should I include that file in the NuGet?

I have just enabled **Create NuGet package on build** in Visual Studio. Is there any other way to do the same?

Comment: What are you using to package this NuGet file?

Comment: I'm using it to have some swipe gestures on the box view. This is similar to using Silent Keyboard in [Touch Tracking Demo](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Effects/TouchTrackingEffect/). @Cheesebaron

Comment: No, _how_ are you actually packaging the NuGet package? MSBuild, some external tool, something else? Provide more context to your question.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/tips-for-net-nuget-package-authors-august-2017-48f07604e4a0 You need to choose which platforms to target and then use conditional compilation to exclude certain things from non-UWP platforms.

Comment: Thanks! Will have a try on this @LexLi